# SML Read binary data from std input

Tags: sml

How can a I read binary data from stdIn (standard input) in SML? I know it's easy for text input using ...

```
TextIO.inputAll TextIO.stdIn
```

... but how can this be done for an input stream of binary data?

Comment: Take a look at [BinIO](http://mosml.org/mosmllib/BinIO.html).

Comment: Sure, but how can I make BinIO work on stdIn?

Comment: I doubt that treating stdin as binary would be portable.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments. As a workaround I am going to encode the binary data as base64 and then use TextIO.inputAll...  "cat image.tif | base64 | my-sml-prog"